# SonarQube does not save project (historical) data

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Both SonarQube 5.4 and 6.1 fail to save project (historical) data for the same 12 of my 64 projects. At first I thought it was related to a version and database upgrade (search SO for “SonarQube 6.1 not calculating lines of code after upgrade and database migration”), but I have both wiped the database, reinstalled SQ, and deleted and recreated the projects from within SQ multiple times to no effect.

As you can see in this screenshot:

[image: SonarQube UI]

SQ does recognize and analyze the files, but doesn't save anything to the database. I ran a project with SQ with logging set to TRACE and the results are [here](http://pastebin.com/YW3Lyk9S).

For anyone who looks at the log and wonders why I am running SQ 5.4, it is because that is apparently the newest version that supports analyzing C# files on non-Windows systems.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: What are the housekeeping settings (Administration > General > Database Cleaner) for these projects?

Comment: All default values for 5.4:
Clean directory/package history: true
Delete closed issues after: 30
Keep only one snapshot a day after: 24
Keep only one snapshot a week after: 4
Keep only one snapshot a month after: 52
Delete all snapshots after: 260

Comment: How often/when do you analyse this project ? Do you use the parameter sonar.projectDate ?

Comment: 1. I have analyzed the projects via Jenkins one or more times a day as I have debugged the issue and/or tuned Jenkins and SQ. Also, some analyses are triggered automatically because of SCM-Git commits. 2. No, but I am running all 60+ projects the same way and only 12 of them have this problem while the rest do not.